# Как сравнить два списка javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как сравнить два списка? И вывести отсутствующий элемент?

```js
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('#list div')].map(div => div.attributes.uid.value);
    const ids2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('#list2 div')].map(div => div.attributes.uid.value);
    var list = ids;
    var list2 = ids2;
    document.write(list,"<br>",list2)
```

```html
<div id="list">

    <div id="1" uid="111"></div>
    <div id="3" uid="113"></div>
    <div id="4" uid="114"></div>
    <div id="5" uid="115"></div>
    <div id="6" uid="116"></div>
</div>

<div id="list2" >

    <div id="getList" uid="112"></div>
    <div id="getList" uid="115"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возьми ключи первого списка, проверь на эквивалентность и доступность в другом

Comment: id не должны совпадать -  getList смотри - это коментарий к коду

Comment: @СергейПетрашко  Вот так удалось решить этот вопрос var arr2 = ids2.filter(e => !~ids.indexOf(e));

Comment: @МестныйДьявол , я написал о том что в html  не должно быть. одинаквовых id -  у тебя. getList  повторяется - если захочешь потом сикать эжлементы через id-  найдешь только 1

Comment: @СергейПетрашко Это понятно спасибо!!! Данный код писал для примера и не как иначе!!! Так более наглядней для корректно задавания вопроса))) Но все равно спасибо что откликнулись!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('#list div')].map(div => div.attributes.uid.value);
    const ids2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('#list2 div')].map(div => div.attributes.uid.value);
    var arr = ids2.filter(e => !~ids.indexOf(e));
    document.write(arr)
```

```html
<div id="list">

    <div id="1" uid="111"></div>
    <div id="3" uid="113"></div>
    <div id="4" uid="114"></div>
    <div id="5" uid="115"></div>
    <div id="6" uid="116"></div>
</div>

<div id="list2" >

    <div id="getList" uid="112"></div>
    <div id="getList" uid="115"></div>
</div>
```